How to specify/start launch configuration by name from vscode extension
I am developing a vscode extension and I would like to launch a debug session from the extension. In my launch.json I have defined two separate launch configurations, (Debug Configuration A, Debug Configuration B)
Is there anyway to launch a specific configuration from an extension?
From the extension I am able to call the following command, but this opens a quickpick to specify the configuration and I don't want that:
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.debug.start');
I would like some kind of command like this,
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.debug.start', 'Debug Configuration A');
Here is a somewhat relevant PR, but this doesn't allow me to specify the exact launch configuration I want and still brings up a quickpick
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/193156

I managed to solve it by doing something like this:
export function getLaunchConfigurations() {
  let rootPath = getRootPath();
  if (rootPath) {
    const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("launch", rootPath);
    const configurations = config.get<any[]>("configurations");

    return configurations;
  }
}

export function getLaunchConfigurationByName(configName: string) {
  let configurations = getLaunchConfigurations();
  if (!configurations) {
    return;
  }

  for (var config of configurations) {
    if (config.name === configName) {
      return config;
    }
  }
}

let debugConfig = getLaunchConfigurationByName(debugTarget);
if (debugConfig) {
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand('debug.startFromConfig', debugConfig);
}

